# Switch between 2 DIVs using checkbox + cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have Div A and Div B. Div B is hidden by default

When I click a checkbox I want it to hide Div A and show Div B, and vice versa when unclicked, and save the hide/show state with a cookie

Can somebody help with this?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/change, http://api.jquery.com/show, http://api.jquery.com/hide

Answer (score 0):

create 2 CSS classes for the style you want, one hidden, one visible, and then use javascript to change the class of the div when the checkbox is updated.

use `document.cookie` to store information as a cookie

e.g.

```
document.cookie = "DivA = Show, DivB = Hide";
```